# Add <strong> tag within JSX with backticks

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I have a div that Is going to render some JSX. within that JSX I want to bold some text. When I add my jsx like this I get an error. I can't seem to find any articles on this exact problem and need some help.

Im sure im missing something very simple

Here is my div

How can I bold only the {Array.length} ?

When I render it shows `Your list contains [object Object] row(s).`

```
 <div>
        <div className='border-solid border-2x border-300rounded-soft text-center cursor-pointer'>
          { `Your list contains ${<strong>{Array.length}</strong>} row(s).`}
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because any thing inside a backtick will be translated into a string.

what you can do is to separate it (you no longer need the backtick in this case):

```
<div>
  <div className='border-solid border-2x border-300rounded-soft text-center cursor-pointer'>
    Your list contains row(s). <strong>{Array.length}</strong> row(s).
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Wojak, This worked! I couldnt seem to find a specific article on this so figured I would ask. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikaPeterson007 kindly accept this answer if this is correct so it would be easier for people with the same issue to find it.

Comment: IamL do you an aston martin?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div className='border-solid border-2x border-300rounded-soft text-center cursor-pointer'>
  { `Your list contains `} <strong>{Array.length} </strong> {`row(s).`}
</div>
```

You can refer the doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: you no longer need the backtick because there are no variables inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<div>
  Your list contains <strong>${Array.length}</strong> row(s).
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work quite well.

- convert strings to pure jsx assuming they are static
- store in jsx json if you have many of them (which good for when you have to do multilingual anyway).

[image]